# Prolog evaluating a number in a list

Tags: prolog

I'm working on a Prolog application that will go through a list of values and copy the values to another list.  If a value is a number, then I want to square that number, otherwise, copy the value.

So given the input:

```
 [k, 4, 9, b]
```

It should yield:

```
 [k, 16, 81, b]
```

Here is what I have:

```
squareMe(X, P) :- P is X * X.

boogie([],[]).
% The next line is where I'm having problems
boogie([X|T], [X|Result]):-
    number(X),
    boogie(T,Result).
boogie([ThrowAway|Tail], [ThrowAway|Result]):-
    boogie(Tail,Result).
```

Right now, this almost works.  So the first thing I tried was:

```
boogie([X|T], [X*X|Result):-
```

Prolog would not evaluate the expression because you need "is".  So I tried:

```
boogie([X|T], [Y is X*X|Result):-
```

That didn't work.  I tried:

```
boogie([k, 4, 9, b], T).
```

My output was:

```
T = [k, _G3648 is 4*4, _G3657 is 9*9, b].
```

Is there a way that I can obtain the square of a number within the list?
i.e.

```
boogie([X|T], [Square of X|Result]):-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
boogie([X|T], [Y|Result]):-
    number(X),
    Y is X*X,
    boogie(T,Result).
```

?

Comment: Thank you.  That did do the trick.  I'm not used to "thinking" in Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

I will admit I haven't done prolog in years, but your approach confuses me a bit. Wouldn't it be easier to simply have a predicate that 'processes' individual tokens, and then use it to recursively process each token in the input list? e.g.

```matlab
%% In file 'boogie.pl'

% 'processToken' predicate
processToken( Unprocessed, Processed )   :- number( Unprocessed ), 
                                            Processed is Unprocessed ^ 2, 
                                            !.
processToken( Unprocessed, Processed )   :- not( number( Unprocessed )),
                                            Processed = Unprocessed.

% 'processList' predicate
processList( [], [] ).   % Base case
processList( InputList, OutputList ) :- [H_in  | T_in  ] = InputList, 
                                        [H_out | T_out ] = OutputList,
                                        processToken( H_in, H_out ),
                                        processList( T_in, T_out ),
                                        !.
```

Then at your prolog console:

```matlab
?- consult( 'boogie.pl' ).
% boogie.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?- processList( [1, 2, a, v, 'hi there', '5', 6], Out ).
Out = [1, 4, a, v, 'hi there', '5', 36].
```

Comment: Yes, your approach does make sense.  I'm a noob in Prolog, so it's taking me a little longer than I thought to "think" in Prolog.  About the only thing your solution shares with mine is that I always use recursion ;)

Comment: Apologies, I only used different names to make the logic clear. My point here is that you should adopt a "top down" approach to help you "think in prolog". If you try to implement everything as one big spaghetti clause, you're bound to get lost in the logic!